# Exceljs - TypeError: Cannot read property 'sheets' of undefined

Tags: exceljs

I got this issue when I tried to read an excel file and I have no clue what caused the issue. Can someone give me a hint?

exceljs version: 2.0.1

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'sheets' of undefined
>       at _callee10$ (/Users/tvi/Documents/BCM projects/sandbox/bulkUpload/node_modules/exceljs/dist/es5/xlsx/xlsx.js:553:43)
>       at tryCatch (/Users/tvi/Documents/BCM projects/sandbox/bulkUpload/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:65:40)
>       at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (/Users/tvi/Documents/BCM projects/sandbox/bulkUpload/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:303:22)
>       at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/Users/tvi/Documents/BCM
>   projects/sandbox/bulkUpload/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:117:21)
>       at asyncGeneratorStep (/Users/tvi/Documents/BCM projects/sandbox/bulkUpload/node_modules/exceljs/dist/es5/xlsx/xlsx.js:3:103)
>       at _next (/Users/tvi/Documents/BCM projects/sandbox/bulkUpload/node_modules/exceljs/dist/es5/xlsx/xlsx.js:5:194)
>       at